# Enable zoom on ios-charts Radar

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

In swift 3 I did this radarChart

[image: radarChart]

But I didn't find how to enable zoom on it and I didn't find if this is even possible.

Here is the code that generated it :

```
func Radar() {
    radarVw.xAxis.valueFormatter = self
    var dataEntries: [RadarChartDataEntry] = []
    for i in 0..<(useri?.skills!)!.count {
        let dataEntry = RadarChartDataEntry(value: (useri?.skills!)![i]["level"].double!)           
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        skillsName.append((useri?.skills!)![i]["name"].string!)
    }

    let chartDataSet = RadarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "skills")

    let chartData = RadarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
    radarVw.xAxis.labelHeight = 0.5
    radarVw.xAxis.labelWidth = 0.5
    radarVw.legend.enabled = false
    radarVw.xAxis.wordWrapEnabled = true

    radarVw.data = chartData
    radarVw.chartDescription?.text = ""
}
```

Comment: By Default Zoom is enable with 2 figure PinchZoom have you tried that ?

Comment: Yes I have tried in the simulator and in my iphone